# Rsize photo to 5" height by 4.5" width in iOS 7+

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, screenshot, image-resizing

I am developing iphone app in which user can add customize the photo by adding text on it. Now I need to convert this photo into 5" height by 4.5" width in iOS7.

I am taking the screenshot of the the view as below to combine photo & labels added to it as below

```
-(UIImage*)customizedImageMain
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.containerView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.containerView.bounds.size);
    [self.containerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

I checked the image from iPod touch with 4" screen. The image size that I get from above code is nearly 4.445" width & 7.889" height.

Now how can I resize this image to exact 5" height & 4.5" width irrespective of device in which app is running ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED Code as per Vin's solution**

```
-(UIImage*)customizedImageFirst
{
    // We want 5" * 4.5" image which can be represented as 1630 * 1458
    // 1630 pixels = 5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch)
    // 1458 pixels = 4.5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch) in terms of pixels.
    CGSize requiredImageSize = CGSizeMake(1458.0,1630.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(requiredImageSize);
    [self.containerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [combinedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,requiredImageSize.width,requiredImageSize.height)];
    UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

Using above code I am getting [this result](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2dirmmx&s=5)

Now if I use code **without** considering UILabels added to customize as below

```
-(UIImage*)customizedImageSecond  // If I use your code
{
    // We want 5" * 4.5" image which can be represented as 1630 * 1458
    // 1630 pixels = 5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch)
    // 1458 pixels = 4.5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch) in terms of pixels.
    CGSize requiredImageSize = CGSizeMake(1458.0,1630.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(requiredImageSize);
    [self.myImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,requiredImageSize.width,requiredImageSize.height)];
    UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

, then I am getting [this image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=aajb00&s=5#.Ulu7NCS5J64)

My UI hierarchy

Main View of UIViewController. I have added another UIView (containerView) in the main view. In this containerView I have added my UIImageView & UILabels. So get the customized image with labels added on it I am taking the screenshot of containerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the custom method that i generally use to scale the image to the desired size. This method take the `newSize` (*For Eg :* `CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(30.0, 30.0);`) as one of the argument. Here, `30.0` is the value in terms of **pixels**.

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

So, you can scale the image in terms of **pixels** using the above method. But you want to scale the image in terms of **inches**. A display device has a limited number of pixels it can display, and a limited space over which to display them.

[Pixel Density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) is a measurement of the resolution of devices and can be calculated in terms of **PPI(Pixels per inch)** or **PPCM(Pixels per centimeter)**.

In your case, you want **5" * 4.5"** image which can be represented as `1630 * 1458 (1630 pixels = 5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch), 1458 pixels = 4.5 inch * (326 pixels / 1 inch))` in terms of pixels.

**Note :** [PPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple) *for Apple iPhone and iPod Touch above 4th Generation is* **326**.

So, If you scale the image with size of `1630 * 1458` then you will get the image of `5"" * 4.5"`. For that you have to pass `CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(1630.0, 1458.0);` in above method.

Comment: Thanks Vin for your solution & great explanation. I really appreciate your explanation. I will check this & let you know.

Comment: If you can see I am using `[self.containerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` so that I can combine the image & labels added on UIImage. If I follow your solution , I am not abke to get the output correctly. Can you tell me whats going wrong ? Please have a look at my update. Thanks

Comment: @iOSAppDev : What is the problem you are facing ? What you are not getting ? Why you can't use my code directly ?

Comment: I will add screenshots of images in next mins .. so you will understand whats going wrong

Comment: First image look smaller & placed in upper left corner where as second image shows correctly.

Comment: @iOSAppDev : You have to change the `x` and `y` co-ordinates in `CGRectMake(0,0,requiredImageSize.width,requiredImageSize.height)` to place the image at correct place.

Comment: can you tell me in which method ? Main , first OR second ? I have updated the method name. Also what should be the values of x & y ? Because if I keep it 0 in customizedImageSecond , its showing me correct image.

Comment: @iOSAppDev : If you are getting the 2nd image properly then why are you not using the same code for 1st image and if you don't want to have your 1st image on upper left corner then you should change the x and y co-ordinates as i mentioned in my above comment to your desired ones.

Comment: I can not use the 2nd method as "user can customize the photo by adding text on it". So I am adding the UILabel on container view & taking the screenshot of container view as mentioned in customizedImageFirst method. My UI hierarchy

Main View of UIViewController. I have added another UIView (containerView) in the main view. In this containerView I have added my UIImageView & UILabels. So get the customized image with labels added on it I am taking the screenshot of containerView.

Comment: @iOSAppDev : I already gave the answer for this Question. It seems like it is a different Question. You should ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help & support. I will try this & if I face issue then I will ask a new question. I really appreciate your help :)